# Calling vision (from google.cloud) Results in 'crash' in Log

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

Have been working on a GCP project involving OCR.  Have attempted to follow the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr), but the first function crashes when I try to upload a file to the trigger bucket. Moreover, cloud shell will not allow me to set the env variable GCP_PROJECT; it returns

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Bad Request], message=[The request has errors
Problems: 
environment_variables:
environment variable name GCP_PROJECT is reserved by the system: it cannot be set by users
]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share the code for OCR you are using in the Cloud Function. You can remove the sensitive data, we just need to see where or how the env variable is being used within the code

Comment: @KevinQuinzel the env variable is used in the cloud shell only, not in the script. If you look at the link I posted, you can see all of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but after some work, I am guessing that the answer is that the .json file with the service account being used in the function had to be exported as GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the gcloud SDK when deploying the function.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr#functions_ocr_setup-python).

Changing

`--set-env-vars "^:^GCP_PROJECT=my_proj:TRANSLATE_TOPIC`

to

`--project my_proj --set-env-vars "^:^TRANSLATE_TOPIC` fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error.
I just follow their own tutorial and there is nothing special or customized.
Actually I got errors in every step of the tutorial and search the internet to fix it.
However I stuck on this one.

Comment: This is not an answer, sb a comment.